# Cannot send gender value properly through javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my database, my gender_id attribute is set to enum ('M', 'F') and **M** is default

Gender form

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <label>Gender: </label>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" >

        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" name="gender" id="**gender_Mid**" class="btn btn-primary active" value="M" onclick="gender(1)"> Male </button>
       </div> // male gender

   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
       <button type="button" name="gender" id="**gender_Fid**" class="btn btn-primary" value="F" onclick="gender(2)"> Female </button>
    </div> //female gender

  </div> <!--End of Button Group-->
</div> <!--End of column-->
```

Ajax/javascript

```
  <script>

     var genderMF = "M";

     function gender(number){

         if(number !== 1 && number !== 2){
             alert('Please select your gender');
         }
         if(number == 1){
             genderMF = "M";
         }
          if(number == 2){
             genderMF = "F";
         }
     }

    function send_registration(){

        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

        var gender = genderMF;

        var parameters=
                "firstname="+firstname+
                ...

                "&gender_id="+gender; // is there an error here?

        var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
                alert(ajax.responseText);

    }
};

        ajax.open("POST","register.php",false);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send(parameters);

} // End of function
```

In my register php there is

```
  // 6. Check for an Gender.
   else if(!in_array($_POST['gender_id'], array('M','F')) ){ 

    echo 'Please enter a gender!';
    exit();

}

 $gender = escape_data($_POST['gender_id']);
```

My javascript/ajax and gender is in the same php file and the register.php container only my php code

The issue whether I click on the female or male button I'm always getting the value M in my database. All the other data are being correctly inserted.

**Issue solve** I just needed to remove this part name="gender" for it to work.

Comment: _"is there an error here"_ - What does your console say? Have you done a `console.log(parameters);` to see how it looks? Have you done a `print_r($_POST)` to see what you actually get? You need to do some debugging...

Comment: use radio instead of `onclick`,  here is an answer : [radio gender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981143/3091563)

Comment: not checkboxes but radio inputs

Comment: can you show the insert query

Comment: I hope that `escape_data()` isn't to escape the data before the DB-call? If it is, you should use Prepared Statements instead...

Comment: But I want to know how to do it with this set up... also only thing that appear in console when I click on either button is gender is not a function... I use prepare statement.

Comment: Remove the "name" from the buttons. Since your not sending the buttons, you don't need to have names.

Comment: Well, if it says that gender isn't a function, no wonder it doesn't change the value. That's the kind of things you need to include in your question. Like the other users mentioned, use a radion button where `M` is the default.

Comment: I remove the "name" and it work!

Comment: @JohnLaimuin there's no impact of `name` here. Debug your code and network request. Or you might not be having any error.

Comment: I just remove the name and it works what you talking about

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but the gender function doesn't appear to be known.

Workaround: use window.

```
var genderMF = "M";

    window.gender =  function (number){

         if(number !== 1 && number !== 2){
             alert('Please select your gender');
         }
         if(number == 1){
             genderMF = "M";
         }
          if(number == 2){
             genderMF = "F";
         }
         console.log(genderMF);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just needed to remove this name="gender" for it to work properly.

Comment: Yes that explains it.